# create function to calculate total score of player on multiple crietera

Tags: excel, vba

My  data  is  somethine  like  this

```
            f         g     h       i    points new  points old
name        runs    balls   4's    6's    
xxy         40         60    2      4      50         26     
aabc        25         45    2      0      25         13.5  
lmn         102        80    10     4      138        70
```

I need  to  calculate  total  points  scored  by  players  on  following criteria

1. player score 1 point for each runs scored earlier he was getting  0.5 point
2. player  score  2  point  for each  6's hit  earlier   he  was  earning 1 point
3. player  score  1   point  for each  4's  hit  earlier he  was  earning  0.5 point
4. Player   score  8  bonus  point  for  scoring  50,  earlier  it  was 4
5. Player   score  16 bonus  point   for  scoring 100  earlier  it  was 8
6. Starting  Eleven  earns   2  points
7. players earns  negative  points  for  low  strike  strike as below

   - strike  rate below  50%         negative point   -6  earlier   -3
   - strike  rate between  50  to  60 negative point  -4  earlier   -2
   - strike  rate between  60  to  70 negative point  -2  earlier   -1
   - Out  for  duck  (zero) negative point -2 (no  change )

I have lengthy excel  formula which is  difficult change  in case any  change in scoring  system.  That is way I propose to put various criteria in one sheet and  player data along with result in another sheet to calculate the point scored  by  player.

That is  way  I propose  to  put  various  criteria   in  one  sheet  and  player data in  another  sheet to  calculate  the  point scored  by  player .

I  have  tried  to  create  function to  start  with  to  calculate  the  point scored by  the player. But  it  I  cannot  end it  properly.  Moreover I want  put criteria in another  sheet  and  calculate  point, How do I create function for that. I have started with something like this:

```
Function tscore(tscore) As Integer
    strikerate = 0
    economyrate = 0 
    halfcentry = 0
    century = 0
    ducks = 0
    wickets = 0
    runs = 0
    SIXERS = 0
    BOUNDERY = 0
    starteleven=2
    If Range("f2") > 0 Then
        runs = Range("F2") * 1
    End If
    If Range("H2") > 0 Then
        BOUNDERY = Range("H2") * 1
    End If
    If Range("H2") > 0 Then
       SIXERS = Range("I2") * 2
    End If
    If Range("F2") / Range("G2") < 50 Then
       strikerate = -3
    Else
       If Range("F2") / Range("G2") >= 50 And Range("F2") / Range("G2") <= 59.9  Then
           strikerate = -2
       Else
           If Range("F2") / Range("G2") >= 60 And Range("F2") / Range("G2") <= 70 Then
               strikerate = -1
           endIf
       endif
    endif
    endif

    tscore=runs+  BOUNDERY+ SIXERS+strikerate+starteleven
end function
```

Actual results should  be

```
 name        points  new     points  old
 xxy           50                26
 aabc          25                13.5
 lmn           138                70
```

But I could  not complete the vba function.

Comment: You need to clarify what you need help with. We can't guess what's your issue, and nobody is going to implement this for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a function, pass in all the information the function needs as arguments. Don't read data from external sources like other cells. If the function needs it, pass it in.

Don't name arguments the same as your function name. To return a value, assign that value to the name of the function. If you have an argument with the same name, it gets confused.

This example doesn't add up because I didn't understand all the conditions, but it should give you a start and you can fix what's wrong.

```
Public Function Score(ByVal Runs As Long, ByVal Balls As Long, ByVal Fours As Long, ByVal Sixers As Long, _
    ByVal RunFactor As Long, ByVal FourFactor As Long, ByVal SixerFactor As Long, _
    ByVal HalfFactor As Long, ByVal CentFactor As Long, _
    ByVal Rate1Factor As Long, ByVal Rate2Factor As Long, ByVal Rate3Factor As Long) As Double

    Dim dReturn As Double

    dReturn = (Runs * RunFactor) + (Fours * FourFactor) + (Sixers * SixerFactor)

    If Runs >= 50 Then dReturn = dReturn + HalfFactor
    If Runs >= 100 Then dReturn = dReturn + (CentFactor - HalfFactor)

    Select Case Runs / Balls
        Case Is < 0.5
            dReturn = dReturn - Rate1Factor
        Case Is <= 59.9
            dReturn = dReturn - Rate2Factor
        Case Is <= 70
            dReturn = dReturn - Rate3Factor
    End Select

    Score = dReturn

End Function
```

You don't need a separate variable (dReturn) but I like to use one. You use the function in a cell like this

```
=score(F2,G2,H2,I2,1,1,2,8,16,3,2,1)
```

Note that my factors are all hardcoded, but you could point those to ranges too

```
=score(F2,G2,H2,I2,Sheet2!A1,Sheet2!A2,Sheet2!A3,Sheet2!A4,Sheet2!A5,Sheet2!A6,Sheet2!A7,Sheet2!A8)
```

Even better, use named ranges

```
=score(F2,G2,H2,I2,Run,Four,Sixer,Half,Century,Strike1,Strike2,Strike3)
```